# $route & $location give Uncaught ReferenceError.. error. When are they visible?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to get a list of the registered routes. I tried running `$route.routes` in the console but I get 'Uncaught ReferenceError....'. Same with `$location`. I get these whether after a breakpoint is hit and using the console or after the page has rendered and using the console. I thought these variables are visible all the time. 
I feel this is a basic question but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

When can I use `$route` or `$location` in the console to examine their properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to get the $route / $location where it's not injected.

1. You could add the break point to one of your controllers 
   or
2. You can use `angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$route').routes` to get list of routes from the console.